# Intersection of rays in occupancy grid maps

Tags: ros-noetic, occupancygrid

The general problem I want to find a solution to is this. Assume I have a discrete grid, and each cell (or pixel) can either only be occupied or unoccupied. Additionally, I have a starting cell location $(x1, y1)$. Then, given a line originating from $(x1, y1)$ making an angle $\alpha$ with the $x$-axis, how could I find the first unoccupied cell along this line?

The motivation behind this is that I want to generate expected laser scan given a known 2D occupancy grid map and robot pose. In theory it seems like a trivial problem. In the book Probabilistic Robotics, Chapter 6.3, beam model, the correct range is modelled by a Gaussian (Equation 6.4). It mentions the true range $z_t^{k*}$ is determined from map $m$ and pose $x_t$ using ray-casting. I am unable to find this implementation.

I read in some ROS forums that such an implementation is provided in `costmap_2d`. In the implementation there (for Noetic at least) the `rayTraceLine` accepts a starting $(x, y)$ and an ending $(x, y)$ location. The end is what I want to compute in the first place. MATLAB has a [`rayIntersection`](https://de.mathworks.com/help/nav/ref/binaryoccupancymap.rayintersection.html) implementation which has exactly what I want. But I cannot use MATLAB and it does not specify how it implements this algorithm.

Any tips to point me in the right direction is appreciated.

Cheers,
Shrini

Answer (score 0):

You want voxel based raycasting or line rasterisation type algorithms. Look into something like either Amenatides et al's Fast Voxel Traversal algorithm or the Bresenham's Line drawing algorithm.

The first one can be a bit tricky, can suffer a bit from floating point type issues so try to reuse an existing one if you can.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input. I have only heard of voxel traversal, but have no idea about it, so I will look into it. 

Bresenham's algorithm would not help me because I do not know the end point pixel.  But for now I will try to set the end pixel based on the the max range of the lidar. Given a range and the angle that it makes with the x-axis should give me the pixel coordinate.

Answer (score 0):

> given a line originating from (x0, y0) making an angle α with the x-axis
> ...
> the rayTraceLine accepts a starting (x0, y0) and an ending (x1, y1) location. The end is what I want to compute in the first place.
> ...
> But for now I will try to set the end pixel based on the the max range of the lidar. Given a range and the angle that it makes with the x-axis should give me the pixel coordinate.

(changed your starting location to x0, y0 and max range location to x1, y1 to match costmap_2d source)

It looks like you have it mostly figured out: `x1 = x0 + max_range * cos(α), y1 = y0 * max_range * sin(α)`, where the x1, y1 is an upper limit on cell location, the occupied cell you are looking for is somewhere between the start and end (if any, and of course the start or end cell could be occupied too), so you have to search along that line between them.

Using bresenham from the start to the end you would check every grid cell location for occupied or not, exit of out of the bresenham for-loop if occupied instead of going all the way to the max range.

The costmap 2d source has a bresenham implementation along with raytraceLine(): https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/noetic-devel/costmap_2d/include/costmap_2d/costmap_2d.h#L359-L412 (there's also 3D voxel code elsewhere in the repo)

Answer (score 0):

There is also an implementation (in C) under the AMCL package :
https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/noetic-devel/amcl/src/amcl/map/map_range.c